# How to calculate cost in discrete Markov transitions

Tags: markov-chains, markov-process, transition-matrix

I am not sure how to handle this problem where there are two types of cost:
( a ) cost of remaining in a state ( state_from = state_to )
( b ) cost of transitioning from one state to another (state_from != state_to)

for example:
I have 3 states, A,B,C

The transition matrix, T, for the chain is:

```
      A     B     C
 A   0.5   0.3   0.2
 B   0.3   0.5   0.2
 C   0.0   0.0   1.0
```

Here, probability of transitioning from A to C is 0.2

and the transition cost matrix, C, is as follows where
cost of remaining in same state is 0 while transitioning to neighboring is 5 units and to the second neighbor is 10 units

```
     A     B     C
 A   0     5     10
 B   5     0     5
 C   10    5     0
```

If the chain starts from A i.e initial state vector is [1, 0, 0], and goes on for n steps, how to get the expected sum of the cost? Specifically,

- what is the cost involved in first transition
- what is the cost involved in nth transition
- what is the total cost involved after all n transitions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A key step toward solving this problem is to transfer the transition costs to the states. You can work with either the expected cost to *leave* a state or the expected one-step cost to *enter* a state. I’ll do the former. If $X_k=i$, then the expected cost of the next step is simply $\sum_{j=1}^3p_{ij}c_{ij}$. If you compute this for all three states, you get a vector $\mathbf r$ of expected exit costs. (I use $\mathbf r$ because the literature usually talks about “rewards” instead of costs.) Now, applying the law of total probability and linearity of expection, if $\mathbf\pi_k$ is the state distribution at time $k$, the expected exit cost for step $k+1$ is $\mathbf\pi_k\mathbf r = \mathbf\pi_0T^{k+1}\mathbf r$, and the total expected cost after $n$ steps is $$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\mathbf\pi_k\mathbf r = \left(\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\mathbf\pi_k\right)\mathbf r = \mathbf\pi_0\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}T^k\right)\mathbf r.$$ Unfortunately, $1$ is an eigenvalue of $T$, so you can’t simply compute the sum on the right as $(I-T)^{-1}(I-T^n)$.

For the system in your question, we have $\mathbf r=(3.5,2.5,0)^T$, so the expected cost of the first transition is $(1,0,0)\mathbf r = 3.5$. For the expected cost of the tenth transition I (well, really Mathematica) get approximately $0.4027$ and the total expected cost up through that time is about $14.014$. If you’re getting different values, check for off-by-one errors in the powers of $T$ that you’re using.

Comment: Thanks. To draw on the example, is the r vector = [3.5 2.5 0] and the cost for 1st transition is 2.5, 10th transition is 0.322 and total cost of 10 transitions is 19.029. State vector after 10 transitions is [.0536 .0536 .8926]

Comment: Correction; cost after 10 transitions is about 10.8365. . This converges to final state of [0 0 1] with a total cost of about 12.125.

Comment: @toing It looks like you’ve computed the costs for an initial state of $[0,1,0]$ instead of $[1,0,0]$. The sums seem off, too.

Comment: Thanks. Will it be too much to ask if you can check my reward vector. I am also attaching python code with results in my original question or below for reference if that helps.

Comment: @toing I’m not going to debug your code, but I have updated my answer with what I think the computed values should be.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate your efforts. Our numbers approx tie out for most part. I think total cost that you have written has a small typo and should be 14.014. In any case, thank you again. I was able to look up markov chain with rewards to get more details on such process. One question I am left with is that most reward vectors are based on state. In my question, reward/cost was upon transition. Is there any literature / link you can point me to where reward vector upon transition has been shown to be expected cost as you have considered(its intuitive, but would help to see it in literature).